# Connect Xamarin application to local ADFS

Tags: xamarin, adfs

I'm trying to create a simple Xamarin application that would need to use a local ADFS to identity the user. Indeed, I wrote an internal web application in ASP.NET Core but the client would like to have a light version as a mobile app, therefore, I need to authenticate the user the same way I do it for the web application: using ADFS 2019 + OAuth/OpenIdConnect.

However, I did some researches on Google and I find nothing talking about that specific case. Most articles concern Azure but I don't want to use Azure, I want to use a local ADFS.

Can anyone provide me with a link or some idea about the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a set of good articles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development) that cover ADFS and OIDC.

The libraries are the same as the Azure ones - just the parameters are different.